# jQuery Plugin Shared Functions and Variables

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am working on a jQuery plugin and am a bit confused on sharing functions and variables between methods within the same namespace. I know that the following will work:

```
    (function($){

    var k = 0;
    var sharedFunction = function(){
                //...
                }

    var methods = {

    init : function() { 
      return this.each(function() {
          sharedFunction();
        });
    },

     method2 : function() { 
      return this.each(function() {
          sharedFunction();
        });
    }
  };

$.fn.myPlugin = function(method) {
    // Method calling logic
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method){
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist here');
    }    
  };

})(jQuery);
```

However, I am wondering if there's a better way to do this. While I understand that the variable "k" and the function "sharedFunction" are not technically global (in that they cannot be accessed directly outside of the plugin), this seems unsophisticated at best.

I know that $.data is an option, but if you have a great deal of variables and functions that need to be accessed by multiple methods in the plugin, this seems like it could turn into a tremendous mess.

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the (arguably) more common pitfalls in Javascript is that `{ }` do not define scope as other C-style languages; functions do.

With that in mind, save for making your variables global, there are two ways (I generally use) to share variables between two separate functions:

#### Declare the functions inside a common function

This is what you're demonstrating above. You're declaring your two functions inside another function (which defines the scope). Anything declared in child-level of the container function is available anywhere in its scope, including the scopes of your two inner functions.

```
// this is a self-calling function
(function () {

    var foo;

    var f1 = function () {
        // foo will be accessible here
    },

    f2 = function () {
        // ... and foo is accessible here as well
    }

})();
```

Honestly, this isn't "unsophisticated" at all, and is commonly done in lieu of not being able to define scope other than function scope in Javascript.

#### Namespacing common members

You *can* define an object in global scope, *and then* just extend that with your variables / functions. You do have to go global, but you're minimizing your footprint by ensuring that you only do it *once*.

```
window.app = {
    foo : 'bar'
};

(function () {

    var f1 = function () {
        // app.foo will be accessible here
    };

})();

(function () {

    var f2 = function () {
        // ... and here as well, even though we're 
        // in a totally different (parent) scope
    };

})();
```

Using `$().data()` may seem viable, but while it definitely has its uses, I somehow can't recommend tacking on that additional overhead for providing the functionality you describe when it can be as easily (and natively) achieved by simple language mechanics (albeit, readability takes a bit of getting used to).